# Quicksort - Java

Tags: java

I'm implementing Quicksort but the answer does not display correctly. I have been finding the errors but don't know where I get wrong. The answer is still 3,5,1,8,6,7,9,2. Can someone tell me what is wrong in my code?

```
public class quicksortJava {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
    int A [] = {3,5,1,8,6,7,9,2};
    quicksort(A,0,A.length-1);
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++ ){
    System.out.print(A[i]+" ");
    }
}
public static void quicksort(int[]A,int start,int end){
    if (start < end){
    int pIndex = partition(A,start,end);
    quicksort(A,start,pIndex-1);
    quicksort(A,pIndex+1,end);
    }
}
public static int partition(int[]A,int start,int end){
    int pivot = A[end];
    int pIndex = start;
    for (int i = start;i < end; i++){
        if (A[i] <= pivot){
            swap(A[i],A[pIndex]);
            pIndex++;
        }
    }
    swap(A[pIndex],A[end]);
    return pIndex;
}
public static void swap(int A,int B){
    int temp = A;
    A = B;
    B = temp;
}
```

Comment: Was @Tachi's answer not good enough? why the downvote?

Comment: It is a correct answer. I think it was downvoted by another person who copy pasted the quick sort code from internet and deleted it when @Tachi objected.

Answer (score 1):

Your swap method does not work, because you are only changing the local variables "A" and "B" within the method "swap". You are not actually changing anything in the list.

Try this:

```
public static void swap(int a, int b) {
    int tmp = list[a];
    list[a] = list[b];
    list[b] = tmp;
}
```

You'll need to change all the calls to "swap", too, so they pass an index rather than a value.

(Also, Java variables are lowercase / camelCase, not uppercase. You have multiple variables called "A", which makes everything confusing.)

Comment: Shouldn't the last statement be ->> list[b] = tmp;

Comment: @shailesh88 yes, that is what I said. <innocent whistling>

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks for your help @shailesh88.

Comment: Btw, it should be noted that objects are call-by-reference while primitives are call-by-value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct answer

```
public static int partition(int[]A,int start,int end){
    int pivot = A[end];
    int pIndex = start;
    for (int i = start;i < end; i++){
        if (A[i] <= pivot){
            //swap(i,pIndex);
            int temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[pIndex];
            A[pIndex] = temp;
            pIndex++;
        }
    }
    //swap(A[pIndex],A[end]);
    int temp = A[pIndex];
    A[pIndex] = A[end];
    A[end] = temp;
    return pIndex;
}
```